# Extract Error string on Php regex (preg_match_all function)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have an **array**:

```
$arr1[0]=SOAP-ENV:Server Market 1
$arr[1]="";
$arr[2]=0;
$arr[3]="|Error : User Name and Password is Failed"
```

the second just **normal variable**:
K
i **merge**:

```
$collarr = array_merged($var1,$othervar);
print_r($collarr);
```

$collarr **result** :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => SOAP-ENV:Server Market 1| 
    [1] =>
    [2] => 0
    [3] => |Error : User Name and Password is Failed
    [4] => SOAP-ENV:Server Market 2| 0 |Error : Failed Mysql query())
```

i parse with **regex**

```
preg_match_all("/[error]+/i",$collarr[0].$collarr[4],$resultarr);
```

**BUT** i just get the result :

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Error [1] => Error ) )
```

What is the best regex pattern to have for have **result like**:

```
"Error Soap-Env:Server market 1: User Name and Password is Failed Server Market"."Error Soap-Env:Server market 2 : Failed Mysql query()"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you concatenate the arrays first? You already had the error message separated, or not?

Comment: you mean $collarr = array_merged($var1,$othervar);? i concatenate coz in future i wanna collect from many array. And my focus in on regex.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the funciont preg_grep, it filters out the array for the specified pattern:

```
$resultarr = preg_grep("/error/i", $collarr);
print_r($resultarr);
```

Prints for me:

```
Array
(
    [3] => |Error : User Name and Password is Failed
    [4] => SOAP-ENV:Server Market 2| 0 |Error : Failed Mysql query()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use methods that include `preg_match_all()` and `preg_grep()`, but those function use regex and are generally less efficient than non-regex-based functions.

If you always have the same data structure that you provided in your sample arrays, then I have a one-liner solution that uses [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), and [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to provide your desired string for each error array.

```
$arr1[0]="SOAP-ENV:Server Market 1";
$arr1[1]="";
$arr1[2]=0;
$arr1[3]="|Error : User Name and Password is Failed";

echo $str1=str_replace("|","",implode(' ',array_filter($arr1)));  // declare and echo

echo "<br>";

$arr2[0]="SOAP-ENV:Server Market 2";
$arr2[1]="";
$arr2[2]=0;
$arr2[3]="|Error : Failed Mysql query()";

echo $str2=str_replace("|","",implode(' ',array_filter($arr2)));  // declare and echo
```

This will output:

```
SOAP-ENV:Server Market 1 Error : User Name and Password is Failed
SOAP-ENV:Server Market 2 Error : Failed Mysql query()
```

You see that if you feed the 4-element array to my 3-function method, it will first remove empty/null/zero values, then combine the remaining elements using a space as glue into a string that will be stripped of all of its pipe characters.

If you are going to do any concatenation/combination/merging of this data, I recommend doing so after the desired string has been generated.

If your actual case has more diverse values and my answer doesn't accommodate your project's complexity, please update your question with some sample input that causes trouble and I'll adjust my method.